# Website rendering intermittently wrong on the iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I'm having a strange issue with my website on the iPad, sometimes the page will just load with a weird margin to the right of text elements. This issue began after I changed the font-family of my page.
The font is Yanone Kaffeesatz which is been loaded from google. The font always loads correctly but since this margin thing never happened before I'm assuming that whatever the issue is it's been caused by the font.

Here is how the font is defined on css:

```
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url('../img/type.png');
      font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz',Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Sometimes the page load correctly:

[image: This is what it should look like]

And some times it loads like this: (It's an intermittent issue but I've observed that I can cause it to load like this by deleting the cache and opening the page)

[image: This is what it sometimes looks like]

Has anyone ever seen this issue before? Any tips on how I can solve it? Thanks!

[Link to site.](http://raphaelcruzeiro.com)

Comment: Please add more details to your posting... some code?  which fonts?

Comment: The font is Yanone Kaffeesatz which is been loaded from google.

Comment: And if you switch back to another font, the problem goes away?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm assuming that this has something to do with the order that the resources are loaded, if the font is already on cache the problem rarely happens.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with fonts to explain your results.  However, you have the advantage in that you _know_ this font is the cause.   Just dump the font for something similar... there are a million others.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I did that. Until I can figure out what the hell os going on I'll leave it on sans-serif. thanks

Comment: There's nothing to figure out... the font is corrupted, out of spec, broken, etc. or there's something unique about it that triggers an obscure iPad rendering bug.  Either way, why waste any more time on such a trivial issue?  There is a website where you can upload a sample piece of text and it will return all matching fonts.  I'm sure you can find something else that matches `Yanone Kaffeesatz`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you removed custom font on your site. 
I can't create the test case on my local network with ipad.
But i suggest you using [FOUT fix for loading custom fonts](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-google-webfont-loader-and-how-to-avoid-font-face-text-flickering-with-it/).

```
<script>
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700:latin' ] }
    };
    (function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("class","wf-loading")
        //  NEEDED to push the wf-loading class to your head
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("className","wf-loading")
        // for IE…
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'false';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })();
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .wf-loading .article.list {visibility:hidden;}
    .wf-inactive .article.list{ visibility:visible;}
    .wf-active .article.list{font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', serif;visibility:visible;}
</style>
```